# TkInter - Can't Get Frames to work correctly and resize

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

TkInter's frames are driving me crazy.  My goal is to have an options frame where I can select some options, then press "Archive" and the TkInter window changes to showing the output from the rest of my script.

I cannot get this to size correctly - there appears to be some additional frame taking up space in the window.

```
import string
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import threading

def main(argv):
    print("In Main")
    for arg in argv:
        print(arg)

class TextOut(tk.Text):

    def write(self, s):
        self.insert(tk.CURRENT, s)
        self.see(tk.END)

    def flush(self):
        pass

class Mainframe(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = OptionsFrame(self)
        self._frame.pack(expand=True)

    def change(self, frameClass):
        # make new frame - for archive output
        self._frame = frameClass(self)
        self._frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        return self._frame

class Mainframe(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = OptionsFrame(self)
        self._frame.pack(expand=True)

    def change(self, newFrameClass):
        # make new frame - for archive output
        self._frame = newFrameClass(self)
        self._frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        return self._frame

class OptionsFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        master.title("Test")
        master.geometry("325x180")
        self.selectedProject = None
        self.initUI(master)

    def initUI(self, master):

        frame1 = Frame(master)
        frame1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        self.label1 = Label(frame1, text="Select Project to Archive, then click Archive")

        self.projectListbox = tk.Listbox(frame1, width=60, height=100)
        self.projectListbox.bind("<<ProjectSelected>>", self.changeProject)

        # create a vertical scrollbar for the listbox to the right of the listbox
        self.yscroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.projectListbox,command=self.projectListbox.yview,orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.projectListbox.configure(yscrollcommand=self.yscroll.set)

        # Archive button
        self.archiveBtn=tk.Button(frame1,text="Archive",command=self.ArchiveButtonClick)

        # Do layout
        self.label1.pack()
        self.projectListbox.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.yscroll.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.archiveBtn.pack(side="bottom", pady=10, expand=False)

        choices = ["test 1", "test 2", "test 3", "test 4", "test 5", "test 6"]
        # load listbox with sorted data
        for item in choices:
            self.projectListbox.insert(tk.END, item)

    def getSelectedProject(self):
        # get selected line index
        index = self.projectListbox.curselection()[0]
        # get the line's text
        return self.projectListbox.get(index)

    # on change dropdown value
    def changeProject(self,*args):
        self.selectedProject = self.getSelectedProject()

    def ArchiveButtonClick(self):
        # Switch to second frame - for running the archive
        self.changeProject(None)
        # Hide existing controls
        self.label1.pack_forget()
        self.projectListbox.pack_forget()
        self.yscroll.pack_forget()
        self.archiveBtn.pack_forget()

        newFrame = self.master.change(ArchivingOutputFrame)
        newFrame.args = [ "-n", self.selectedProject]
        newFrame.start()

# Frame shown while archive task is running
class ArchivingOutputFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        master.title("Test Frame 2")
        master.geometry("1000x600")
        # Set up for standard output in window
        self.var = tk.StringVar(self)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.var)
        #lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
        lbl.pack(anchor="nw")

    def start(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.process)
        t.start()

    def process(self):
        main(self.args)

if __name__=="__main__":
    # If command line options passed - skip the UI
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        main(sys.argv[1:])
    else:
        app=Mainframe()
        text = TextOut(app)
        sys.stdout = text
        sys.stderr = text
        text.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
        app.mainloop()
```

Here is what I get in the UI; note this is showing the UI hierachy from Microsoft's Spy++ - there is a frame I didn't create (at least I don't think I did) that is at the bottom of the window and taking up half of the UI area; this is the yellow highlight.  My options pane is thus squeezed into the top half.
[image: UI regions]

Resize also doesn't work - if I resize the window, I get this:

[image: Resized window only growing bottom]

When I click the button and the code to remove the options frame and put in the frame that is capturing stdout/stderr from the main script runs, I get this:

[image: UI from stdout]

Now the extra space appears to be at the top!

Thanks for any ideas - I know I could switch to using the "Grid" UI layout engine, but this seems so simple - I'm not doing anything sophisticated here that shouldn't work with pack.

Comment: This is way too much code. If the problem is with frames and extra space, we only need a few widgets and almost none of the other code. Please see [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a lot of complicated code. It would be easier to debug if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

However; the bottom Frame is the TextOut() widget that you pack after Mainframe():

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = Mainframe()
    text = TextOut(app)  # This one
    sys.stdout = text
    sys.stderr = text
    text.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    app.mainloop()
```

You'll have an easier time debugging if you give each widget a bg colour and then give them all some padding so you can easier identify which widget is inside which widget.

Comment: LOL - this _was_ an attempt to produce that, obviously not successful.  Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look at that.